# android alpha animation remove alpha

Tags: android, android-animation, fadein, fadeout, alpha

I have Imageview in my Xml file and i have 0.6f alpha in my imageview.this is a code

```
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:alpha=".60"
  android:id="@+id/u_go_dashboard_bill"/>
```

now i want to remove alpha with animation with fade in fade out .i mean alpha 100%.i also wrote some java code but i can't change it

```
  AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F);
            alpha.setDuration(150);
            alpha.setFillAfter(true);
            dashboardBillAvatar.startAnimation(alpha);
```

how i can solve my problem?if anyone knows solution please help me
p.s i never worked alpha animations and i don't know how i can use it
thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.u_go_dashboard_bill);
yourImageView.animate().alpha(1.0).setDuration(150).start();
```